# I am getting an error in prolog in vs code please check

Tags: visual-studio-code, prolog

This is the code:

```
dog(rottweiler).  
cat(sphynx).        dog(poodle).  
dog(bulldog).       cat(bengal).  
dog(dobermann).  
cat(himalayan). cat(singapura).
```

ND THE ERROR IS:-
Warning:    Clauses of dog/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning:    Earlier definition at c:/users/dell/desktop/prolog/dog:1
Warning:    Current predicate: cat/1
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous dog/1. to suppress this message
Warning: c:/users/dell/desktop/prolog/dog:4:
Warning:    Clauses of cat/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning:    Earlier definition at c:/users/dell/desktop/prolog/dog:2
Warning:    Current predicate: dog/1
Warning:    Use :- discontiguous cat/1. to suppress this message.
TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog, an *n*-ary predicate *p*, for *n*≥0, is defined by a **procedure**, which consists of one or more **clauses** whose conclusions are terms of the form *p*(*a**1, ..., *a***n*), where each *a*_*i* is an argument. Clauses belonging to the same procedure are expected to be declared in sequence, **contiguously**.

When the clauses of two or more distinct procedures appear interleaved in the source code, the compiler produces the warning messages you get. To suppress such messages, you can use a directive of the form `:- discontiguous predicate/arity`.

For example:

```
:- discontiguous dog/1.
:- discontiguous cat/1.

dog(rottweiler).
cat(sphynx).
dog(poodle).
dog(bulldog).
cat(bengal).
dog(dobermann).
cat(himalayan).
cat(singapura).
```

Note, however, that the best option is to **follow the Prolog convention** and modify your code as follows:

```
% clauses of the first procedure

dog(rottweiler).
dog(poodle).
dog(bulldog).
dog(dobermann).

% clauses of the second procedure

cat(sphynx).
cat(bengal).
cat(himalayan).
cat(singapura).
```